# Call external Python class function from inside Haxe

Tags: python, haxe

Let's assume that I have the following class in Python:

```
class TestPy:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self):
        return("Hello World")
```

and I want to call the function `TestPy.f` from within Haxe. I can then tell the compiler of this function by specifing an extern class via

```haxe
extern class TestPy { 
    public function new():Void;
    public function f():String;
}
```

and then use this declaration in order to call this function

```haxe
class Test {
    public static function main():Void {
        var py:TestPy = new TestPy();
        trace(py.f());
    }
}
```

This compiles, however the generated code looks like this:

```
# Generated by Haxe 3.4.7
# coding: utf-8
class Text:
    __slots__ = ()
    @staticmethod
    def main():
        py = TestPy()
        print(str(py.f()))
Text.main()
```

which is not working because the module the with `TestPy` class never gets imported in the code:

> NameError: name 'TestPy' is not defined

So my question is how can I advice Haxe to add an import statement (e.g. `from testmodule import TestPy`) to the generated code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `@:pythonImport` metadata to your extern.
So, something like:

```
@:pythonImport('testmodule', 'TestPy')
extern class TestPy {...
```

Disclaimer: haven't tested this, so that may not be the exactly correct answer, but the metadata is [documented in the manual](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-metadata.html).